# Input not being scanned

Tags: java

I have a do while loop which asks for the user if he/she wants to continue the program or not. BUt the problem is, after printing the "Continue?" it does not scan the user's input, rather it ends the program already. What is the problem?

```
  System.out.println("Continue? (y/n)");
  choice = in.nextLine();
} while(key.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

Comment: Where do you set your `key` variable?

Comment: sorry it must be while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

Answer (score 1):

```
while(key.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

should be:

```
while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

or better, use `startsWith(` for more Unix'y behavior.

Comment: ow sorry. that was a mistake. it really should be while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); but it still doesn't scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for reading user input in console application.